# Meaning of \d{1-3 }in regular expression

Tags: regex

I've been searching for a long time but didn't find an answer for my question, can tell me what the meaning of

```
(?:[-\w\d{1-3}]+\.)+
```

and not

```
(?:[-\w\d{1,3}]+\.)+
```

I don't understand the {1-3} part and can't find anywhere what it's mean.
Thank you

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but that pattern is complete garbage and whoever wrote it had no idea what they were doing. See this: https://www.debuggex.com/r/Fh0mC-RVZ0J2WRbe

Comment: The duplicate closing reason is incorrect, but yes, this regex doesn't make sense. The character group`[]` includes a dash, a word character, a digit (which generally is already a word character), an opening brace, digits 1 to 3 (inclusive), and a closing brace. So all the extra digits references are redundant.

Comment: `\d` matches a digit and this `{1-3}` matches literal `{1-3}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything between `[]` are characters to be matched. So it matches each of those characters:

- `-` the literal character -
- `\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\d` match a digit `[0-9]`
- `{` the literal character {
- `1-3` a single character in the range between 1 and 3
- `}` the literal character }

the `1-3` makes no sense there, as well as the `\d`. Both are included in `\w`
Even what you would say that is correct `{1,3}` inside the `[]` makes no sense.